# Knockout: change value of input dependent on drop down value

Tags: knockout.js

I have a drop down that allows a person to select a pricing option, one of them being "Discount".  If "Discount" is selected, I need the cost field to become a negative value.  This was easy to achieve.

My problem is: how can I make the cost field negative, after typing a positive value, by detecting if the pricing option drop down is on "Discount".  Below is a simplified version of my model and what I have for the logic to turn the number into negative if the drop down is changed.

```
var row = function (pricing, c) {
 var self = this;
 self.cost = ko.observable(c ? c : "0").extend({ required: true });
 self.pricingOptions = ko.observableArray([
  { id: "1", value: "Freight" },
  { id: "2", value: "Discount" }
 ]);
 self.selectedPricing = ko.observable(pricing ? pricing : "");
 self.selectedPricing.subscribe(function (value) {
  if (value == "Discount") 
   {
    if (parseFloat(self.cost()) > 0) {
    self.cost(-parseFloat(self.cost()));
   }
  } else {
   if (parseFloat(self.cost()) < 0) {
    self.cost(-parseFloat(self.cost()));
   }
  }
 });
}
```

EDIT: here is jsfiddle of what i have:http://jsfiddle.net/tt1mtb19/3/

notice that if Discount is already selected, when you type in an amount into the field, it stays positive, no matter what.  It only changes to negative if you change the drop down back to Freight, and then to Discount.

Comment: can you use something like `self.discount = ko.computed(function(){return self.cost() * -1})`

Comment: @dan I am already doing that, that that is not what my question was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is properly multiply with highest negative integer i.e `-1` and most importantly use `blur` event .

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function (pricing, c) {
    var self = this;
    self.cost = ko.observable(c ? c : 0);
    self.selectedPricing = ko.observable(pricing ? pricing : "");
    self.pricingOptions = ko.observableArray([{
        id: "1",
        value: "Freight"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        value: "Discount"
    }]);
    self.selectedPricing.subscribe(function (value) {
        switch (value) {
            case "1":
                self.cost(parseFloat(self.cost()));
                break;
            case "2":
                self.cost(-1 * parseFloat(self.cost()));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
    self.modify = function () {
        if (self.selectedPricing() == 2 && self.cost() > 0) {
            self.cost(-1 * parseFloat(self.cost()));
        }
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(0, 2));
```

sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27496/)**

Comment: I already know how to change the value of the text field to a negative after selecting "Discount".  The problem I have is how can I change the value of the text field after just typing in a positive value AFTER the "Discount" has already been selected previously.  In your example, set the drop down to "Discount", then type in 1 in the field.  After you remove focus from the field, it stays at 1.  I need it to change to -1 automatically IF "Discount" is already selected.

Comment: sure . all you need is a `blur` event which does your job conditionally check the update @luthan

Comment: ah yes!  i didn't think of using blur.  somehow i was expecting to achieve this via extenders, but that would just complicate things.  thanks a bunch.